# Grab airport name based on airport code from json data

Tags: javascript, json, country-codes

Working on a flight booking website. Have a `json` file which contains the airport codes, city name and country name.

`[{"iata":"UTK","lon":"169.86667","iso":"MH","status":1,"name":"Utirik Airport","continent":"OC","type":"airport","lat":"11.233333","size":"small"}]`

Now if my `iata` airport code matches to `UTK` i want to return the name.

Comment: Use the for loop to iterate over the array and check for the code.

Comment: Please do not add a PHP tag. Your tag is invalid as the question does not relate to PHP. Your question is now a bad question because it is not clear what you are asking. Do you want a solution in javascript or PHP? You cannot have both - unless your specific requirement uses both technologies... in which case you need to show your current code attempts. I will have to downvote this question until you improve it, sorry

Comment: Here PHP and json have relation know, If some body searching for the same code in php, This answers might help them. So i added the tag

Comment: @RadhakrishnaRayidi: SO doesn't work like that! You cannot ask generic questions asking for solutions in multiple languages. Pick one or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the object within the `Array` by its `iata`:

```
var arr = [{"iata":"UTK","lon":"169.86667","iso":"MH","status":1,"name":"Utirik Airport","continent":"OC","type":"airport","lat":"11.233333","size":"small"}];

function findByCode(arr, iata){
    var filtered = arr.filter(function(e){return e.iata = iata});
    return (filtered.length == 1) ? filtered[0]:undefined;
}

console.log(findByCode(arr,"UTK").name);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dE9nP/

Comment: Minified version ! Thanx dude

Answer (score 0):

This is basic searching! You need to loop over the array, and check each item for the matching code, then return the result. Here is a function:

```
function findAirport(myArray, iata){
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        var item = myArray[i];
        if(item["iata"] === iata){
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can use that function like so:

```
var airports = [{"iata":"UTK","lon":"169.86667","iso":"MH","status":1,"name":"Utirik Airport","continent":"OC","type":"airport","lat":"11.233333","size":"small"}];
var match = findAirport(airports, "UTK");
if(match){
    console.log("name = " + match.name);
}
```

---

Just to highlight my preference to using simple for loops over other functions such as `filter`, [here is a performance test](http://jsperf.com/filter-versus-loop) comparing my answer to the other one that uses `filter`. I know it's meaningless in most real use cases, but I wanted to keep a reference to the jsperf link :)

**NOTE**: This answer was provided before the question tags were edited. At the time of posting this question was asking for a javascript solution

Comment: Wow ! Worked like charm :) Thanks dude

Comment: @RadhakrishnaRayidi: Hopefully you can take this new knowledge and apply it whenever you need to search arrays in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '[{"iata":"UTK","lon":"169.86667","iso":"MH","status":1,"name":"Utirik Airport","continent":"OC","type":"airport","lat":"11.233333","size":"small"}]';
 $data = json_decode($string);
echo count($data);
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
if($data[$i]->iata == 'UTK') echo $data[$i]->name;
}
```

you can use file_get_contents if the data in a file instead of $string;

Comment: This is not a PHP question. Javascript only answers please

Comment: Even thow, The answer helps for PHP Developers also. Thats y +1

Comment: @RadhakrishnaRayidi: This isn't how stackoverflow works. Answers should answer the exact question. Not be a reference point for alternate language implementations. There are already loads of questions (with answers) about how to search a JSON array in PHP

Comment: I think the question is tagged as (javascript,php) question, So one of the two solutions is enough.

Comment: @JohnTaa: It wasn't to start with... and now it is incorrectly tagged. Do you think it would be acceptable to add other languages too? Shall we add a C# answer? maybe a Java one too?